# MySQL return a table of Group By Functions?

Tags: mysql, sql, analytics

My goal is to see how the average changes as chunks of data are chopped off. I have a basic query that returns a set of averages:

```
SELECT AVG(col1), AVG(col2), AVG(col3), COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE col1 > 100;
```

In concept, I want to vary the `WHERE` clause and thus get a table of results:

```
SELECT AVG(col1), AVG(col2), AVG(col3), COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE col1 > 100;

SELECT AVG(col1), AVG(col2), AVG(col3), COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE col1 > 200;
```

except for many conditions, and this only returns the last row. How can I iterate to obtain many sets of averages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do this by creating a table of the cut-off values.  Something like:

```
select c.cutoff, avg(t.col1), avg(t.col2), avg(t.col3), count(*)
from (select 100 as cutoff union all
      select 200
     ) c left join
     table t
     on t.col1 > c.cutoff
group by c.cutoff;
```

Comment: So I am forced to use an external program to create a list of conditions? `select 200 union all` + `select 300 union all` + ... + `select 1000000`

Comment: @user3477312 . . . Well, you have to get them into the query *somehow*.  If they are already in a table (or if you put them into a temporary table), then you can just use that table.